# How to change background with day/night time?

Tags: java, android, time, android-drawable, localtime

In my application I want to change background with **Day/Night** time.
My mean is I want check **time** if time is **night** set **night background** from `drawable` and when **time is Day** set day **background** from `drawable`.

Sorry for my bad question, I am an amateur and really need your help.
How can I do it in android?

Comment: http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-daynight-theme-example-using-appcompat-v23-2/

Comment: Do you have any idea on what you need to do ? A step by step solution ? If not, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a code something like this, by specifying the hours you consider in morning and the hours you consider as night.

I considered the time from `06:00 - 18:00` as **morning** and `18:00 - 05:00` as **night**. Change it accordingly.

```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   int time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if(time >= 6 && time < 18){

    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.morning);     

     }else if (time >= 18 && time < 6){

    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.night);

    }
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by @AxelH, it would be better to just specify either one of the time (morning or night only). The code would be something like:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   int time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if(time >= 6 && time < 18){

    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.morning);     

     }else{

    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.night);

    }
```

Comment: And what about between `05:00 -06:00` ? Just use `if(time >= 6 && time < 18){ ...} else { ...}` to prevent this kind of mistake

Comment: @AxelH Yeah, that's a better approach. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
int gettime  = time.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
if(Calendar.AM == gettime)
    Log.d("AM"+now.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

Comment: thanks my dear friend for your help. but I am amateur. can you send to me full code? for example how can I check now is day or night for set background! please help me